# Compliance Center - eDiscovery API

Tags: office-365, compliance-center

There is a post from 2014 around an interface to eDiscovery in here stating there is none. However is there any changes for this? We consider to use eDiscovery to backup all of out sites, but need an API to do this. Any one knows of any way to create seaches etc in Office 365 eDiscovery through API?